# PHP's DomXPath not working the way it was expected

Tags: php, html, xpath, domxpath

I'm trying to parse this HTML page: http://www.valor.com.br/valor-data/moedas

For a simple start, I'm trying to get all `td` elements with `class="left"` and echoing their inner texts. What I'm struggling to understand is why this code:

```
    $finder = new DomXPath($dom);
    $tds = $finder->query("//*[@class='left']");
    foreach ($tds as $td) {
        echo $td->textContent;
    }
```

gives me the expected output (a bunch of words that belong to those `td` elements which aren't worth pasting here) while this:

```
    $finder = new DomXPath($dom);
    $tds = $finder->query("//td[@class='left']");
    foreach ($tds as $td) {
        echo $td->textContent;
    }
```

finds nothing. I've also tried `$finder->query("//td")` to simply get all `td` elements, but it's like DomXPath doesn't recognize tag names. Has anyone ever faced this same problem?

Comment: `$finder->query("//td")` should work for all td tags

Comment: @drakes it doesn't. That's the reason of the question.

Comment: You typed `$finder->query("td")` which will do nothing

Comment: I  actually tried both ways, none worked. I'll edit there.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I ran your codes on the live site and get back tds with `Dolar ComercialDolar ... **Real/Libra Britanica **` with both your methods above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not tested, but this is probably a namespace issue. Your input page is XHTML and has correctly declared an XHTML namespace. Therefore, you need to register a namespace prefix and use that prefix in your query.

Something like this

```
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$finder->registerNamespace("x", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
$tds = $finder->query("//x:td[@class='left']");
foreach ($tds as $td) {
    echo $td->textContent;
}
```